# Understanding validation based database concurrency control protocol

Tags: database-theory, databases

[Database book by Korth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0073523321) explains validation protocol as follows :

> To perform the validation test, we need to know when the various phases of transactions took place. We shall, therefore, associate three different timestamps with each transaction $T_i$:
>
> 1. **Start($T_i$)**,the time when $T_i$ started its execution.
> 2. **Validation($T_i$)**, the time when $T_i$ finished its read phase and started its validation phase.
> 3. **Finish($T_i$)**,the time when $T_i$ finished its write phase.
>
> The validation test for transaction $T_i$ requires that, for all transactions $T_k$ with $TS(T_k) < TS(T_i)$, one of the following two conditions must hold:
>
> 1. Finish($T_k$) < Start($T_i$). Since $T_k$ completes its execution before $T_i$ started, the serializability order is indeed maintained.
> 2. The set of data items written by $T_k$ does not intersect with the set of data items read by $T_i$, and $T_k$ completes its write phase before $T_i$ starts its validation phase Start($T_i$) $<$ Finish($T_k$) $<$ Validation($T_i$)). This condition ensures that the writes of $T_k$ and $T_i$ do not overlap. Since the writes of $T_k$ do not affect the read of $T_i$, and since $T_i$ cannot affect the read of $T_k$, the serializability order is indeed maintained.

**Doubt**

How second point says "writes of $T_k$ do not affect the read of $T_i$"?

Start($T_i$) is the timestamp when $T_i$ started its execution.

Validation ($T_i$): is the timestamp when $T_i$ finishes its read phase and starts its validation phase.

I believe that mean read phase start at Start($T_i$) and ends at Validation($T_i$) ?

Also Finish($T_k$) is timestamp when $T_k$ finished its write phase.

So, I believe Start($T_i$) $<$ Finish($T_k$) $<$ Validation($T_i$) means write of $T_k$ overlaps with read of $T_i$ and hence write of $T_k$ can affect read of $T_i$.

Am I missing something stupid?

Comment: You're missing: "The set of data items written by `Tk` does not intersect with the set of data items read by `Ti`,". So yes `Tk`'s Write overlaps `Ti`'s Read, but it's distinct data items so they don't interfere.

Comment: This is one such question where I prove my stupidity. I always read it fast and interpreted that the condition Start(Ti) < Finish(Tk) < Validation(Ti) was ensuring non intersecting data items of Tk and Ti. Such a stupidity!!! Dont know if this question deserves any upvote (it already have one!!!). Probably the person who upvoted did the same!!!

Comment: @AntC Now next doubt.. it says "... (Start(Ti) < Finish(Tk) < Validation(Ti)). This condition ensures that the writes of Tk and Ti do not overlap." I understand that the condition "The set of data items written by Tk does not intersect with the set of data items read by Ti" ensures that writes of Tk don't affect reads of Ti. But does "Start(Ti) < Finish(Tk) < Validation(Ti)" is required to ensure the same? And if not, then why is that condition there? Why it will not work if Finish(Tk) > Finish(Ti)? After all the data items are non intersecting.

Comment: It doesn't say anything about the Writes of `Ti`; those are not necessarily the same data items as Reads of `Ti`. In particular, the Writes of `Ti` might include some data items that coincide with the Writes of `Tk`. In practice that's likely: could be both `Tk` and `Ti` add to the same accumulator or append to the same logfile.

Comment: I guess I am getting it, now, finally...

Consider: Start(Ti) < Finish(Tk) < Validation(Ti))

This ensures that "writes" of Tk and Ti do not overlap

However "writes" of Tk and "reads" of Ti still can overlap. In this case, it is ensured that "writes" of Tk does not affect "reads" of Ti by putting condition: "the set of data items written by Tk does not intersect with the set of data items read by Ti"

I hope thats all what point 2 meant to say. Please confirm if I miss something or am wrong with something?